# UsinAngular hash location strategy routing in URL protected by Ping Access, and the content after # is getting lost on login flow

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, ping

We are using MVC framework integrated with angular mechanism. We are using Angular Hash location strategy routing in URL protected by Ping access, and the content after # is getting lost on login flow. Ping Authentication gets the URL from the Target URL. Since the # is present in the URL , the URL before # is only getting loaded as target URL and hence it gets redirected to default page instead of target page.
Is there any way we could handle this from application(MVC) end.

Expectation is that the URL should be navigated to the target page instead default page